# Login failed in github for window

Tags: github-for-windows

I installed Github for window and I can't connect to my git hub account.

I tried to reinstall several times, but I always end up with the following error:

login failed

Unable to retrieve your user info from the server.  A proxy server might be interfering with the request.

I don't use a proxy and I disabled the windows firewall without success.  What am I missing here? Am I suppose to NAT a port on my router?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message is really misleading.  The issue wasn't linked to a proxy configuration.

After running the DOS command line `sfc /scannow`, I've been able to find the source of the problem.  It turned out that one of my Windows dll (rasman.dll) was corrupted.  I replaced the dll and now everything is back to normal.

Comment: Most of user said about updating .Net framework in this link: https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/2044 , I'm trying sfc /scannow (May need restart computer) and if didn't solve I must try updating .Net framework.

Comment: I don't know why but after sfc /scsnnow can't login just same as before, then I closed GitHub app and run it again and now everything is OK.

Answer (score 10):

Update the latest .NET Framework 4.5.1

Her is the url : [.NET 4.5.1 download link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40773)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't test your solution as I already repaired the corrupted file. Can someone confirm if the .Net Framework 4.5.1 fixes the corrupted rasman.dll or if we are facing distinct issues?

Comment: Unsure about the corrupted rasman.dll, but updating to 4.5.1 fixed the issue for me. The hardest thing was figuring out I needed to use I.E to get the download...

Answer (score 5):

If updating the .Net Framework and running sfc /scannnow does not work, try to re-install the GitHub for Windows app, make sure that you uninstall it completely by manually erasing the following directories:

- %LocalAppData%\GitHub
- %AppData%\GitHub

More information on the unistall procedure on: https://help.github.com/articles/uninstalling-github-for-windows

Comment: Nothing in here is working.  My rasman.dll is not corrupted, I have .NET 4.5.2, 4.5.1 Multi-Targeting Pack, 4.5.1 Multi-Targeting Pack (ENU), and 4.5.1 SDK, and even after uninstalling and manually deleting all app data files for GitHub, I still can't log in.

Answer (score 3):

Please update your .NET framework ..
This will solves the problem ..

I also faced the same problem. Meanwhile I installed the Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012 which updates the .Net Framework itself ..

Unfortunately the problem solved ..

Answer (score 3):

A few people have posted saying that other recommended solutions did not help.

I found one machine that was reproducing this error message, even after attempting all of the solutions posted so far.

It turned out that someone had installed AVG with some restrictive firewall settings. Setting the firewall to "Allow All" or "Interactive" modes allowed me to log in.

Comment: You're the first one to mention a solution that was really linked to the communication itself... your answer is a great addition that would help people to isolate the real problem hidden behind this broad error message.